# How to use event listener to toggle class to individual list item

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, toggle, addeventlistener

So I'm trying to make a simple to do list app.  I want to add the class "checked" to list items when they are clicked on.  I was trying to use event delegation to do this but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.  I wasn't sure if I should use "addEventListener" or "onclick."  And what is the difference really?  I'm sort of new to javascript so if you could explain accordingly I'd appreciate it.

```
<div id="todoList">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <form id="todoForm">
        <input id="todoInput">
        <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Click Here</button>
      </form>
    <div id="listText">
      <ul id="list">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS

```
#todoList {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black

}
#listText {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 85px;
}

ul li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

The script

```
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(listItem);
}


  var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "li"){
      e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were actually really close!

```
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(listItem);
}

var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "LI"){
    e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
  }
});
```

Your first issue was that you were doing `document.getElementById('ul')`, your `ul` element's ID was actually `list`. Just a silly mistake.

I actually had to open devtools and put a breakpoint in on your conditional to check what had been clicked on.

Turns out `e.target.tagName` was evaluating to `LI` not `li`.

Just needed to change the check to `LI`

As for how to use events. `onclick` will do the same job as `addEventListener`. The way that you've done it here with event delegation is pretty much as good as you're gonna get it with vanilla JS. It all really comes down to personal preference at the end of the day, some frameworks may have you setup events through element attributes and some will have you set them up with event listeners, you could mix and match if you wanted. It's really down to you and your team (if it's a collaborative project).

Comment: Ahh okay!  Thank you!  And yes I just looked up the tag name issue... I guess when using tag name it always returns uppercase.  Is there a way to do it other than evaluating the tag name?

Comment: Definitely! Although I'm not sure you'll be entirely impressed with the solution :) I personally think that checking the tagName in this instance is fine, but an alternative would be to add a class to your `li` when you add it to the list. You can then check if the item has that class with `element.classList.contains(class)`. If you need an example let me know and I'll make a codepen quickly but it should be fairly straightforward to do with what you already have :) Also, pro-tip, learn to use devtools early, they're super helpful: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Ah, yes I probably should've done that, but I'm actually just using codepen and figured it was something wrong with my logic. Haha, guess I underestimated myself!  I did see a few tutorials/examples where they used the class, but this seems like added work.  Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: No worries! Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `.delegate`

```
$(document).delegate('h', 'click', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        document.getElementById('chkod').value = id;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with uppercase `LI`.For case insensitive search use `localeCompare` & there is no element with id `ul`

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(listItem);
}


var ul = document.getElementById("list");
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.localeCompare("li")) {

    e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
  }

});
```

```css
#todoList {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}

#listText {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 85px;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div id="todoList">
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <form id="todoForm">
    <input id="todoInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Click Here</button>
  </form>
  <div id="listText">
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know about localCompare. I noticed you spelled it different in the actual code snippet though, instead it is localeCompare.  Was the first just a typo?

Comment: @bexter yes typo.fixed it